# Can I pass a view model to action link to generate a route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to create a link that will be based on my search criteria. For example:

```
localhost/Search?page=2&Location.PostCode=XX&Location.Country=UK&IsEnabled=true
```

Parameters in this link are the values of properties in my SearchViewModel.

Ideally I'd like to have something on the lines of:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search","User", Model.SearchCriteria)
```

Is this supported by default or do I need to pass properties of my view model into RouteValueDictionary type object and then use that?

My goal is to write a paging helper which would generate page numbers and append the search criteria parameters to the generated links.

E.g.

```
@Html.GeneratePageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("Index"), Model.SearchCriteria)
```

I've combined your solutions with suggestion from PRO ASP.NET MVC 3 book and ended up with the following:

Helper for generating links. Interesting part is pageUrlDelegate parameter which is later used to invoke Url.Action for generating links:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfoViewModel pagingInfo, 
                                        Func<int,String> pageUrlDelegate)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");                                
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrlDelegate(i));
        tagBuilder.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
        result.Append(tagBuilder.ToString());               
    }            

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
}
```

Then in the view model:

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("Index","Search", new RouteValueDictionary()
    {
            { "Page", x },
            { "Criteria.Location.PostCode", Model.Criteria.Location.PostCode },   
            { "Criteria.Location.Town", Model.Criteria.Location.Town},
            { "Criteria.Location.County", Model.Criteria.Location.County}
    }))
)
```

I'm still not happy with property names in Strings, but It'll have to do for now.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Ideally I'd like to have something on the lines of:
>
> `@Html.ActionLink("Search","User", Model.SearchCriteria)`

Unfortunately that's not possible. You will have to pass properties one by one. You could indeed use the overload which takes a `RouteValueDictionary`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Search",
    "User",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Location.PostCode", Model.SearchCriteria.PostCode },
        { "Location.Country", Model.SearchCriteria.Country },
        { "IsEnabled", Model.IsEnabled },
    })
)
```

Of course it's probably better to write a custom ActionLink helper to do this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString GeneratePageLink(this HtmlHelper<MyViewModel> htmlHelper, string linkText, string action)
    {
        var model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
        var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Location.PostCode", model.SearchCriteria.PostCode },
            { "Location.Country", model.SearchCriteria.Country },
            { "IsEnabled", model.IsEnabled },
        });
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, action, values);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.GeneratePageLink("some page link text", "index")
```

Another possibility is to pass only the `id` and have the controller action fetch the corresponding model and values from wherever you fetched it initially in the controller action that rendered this view.

Comment: Hi Darin, thank you for your reply. I will probably use your second advise and create a helper for generating page links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code taken from Steve Sanderson's [Tekpub samples](https://github.com/tekpub/MasteringASPNETMVC2/tree/master/JobAds) that is broadly what you're looking for. First define an extension method on your object -

```
public static RouteValueDictionary DetailsRouteValues(this JobAd jobAd)
{
    return new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        { "controller", "Jobs" },
        { "action", "Details" },
        { "id", jobAd.JobAdId },
        { "country", MakeSimpleUrlSegment(jobAd.LocationCountry) },
        { "city", MakeSimpleUrlSegment(jobAd.LocationCity) },
        { "title", MakeSimpleUrlSegment(jobAd.Title) }
    };
}
```

Then call `Html.RouteLink` using that method -

```
<%= Html.RouteLink(ad.Title, ad.DetailsRouteValues())%>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for an alternative solution. I need to decide whether it's right for me to extend my search criteria with a method to return route values. I like to keep my view models lite.